# Powershell regex on command output for NLTEST

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell

Running:

```
nltest /sc_query:domain /server:servername
```

Produces:

```
Flags: 30 HAS_IP  HAS_TIMESERV 
Trusted DC Name \\hostname.domain 
Trusted DC Connection Status Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
The command completed successfully
```

What I want to grab into a $ is after the \\ just the 'hostname' only.

So far have: '(?<=\\\\).*' (so Expresso Regex util tells me)
This grabs everything after '\\'

How can I code this in PowerShell so I only get the hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the `-match` operator like so:

```
nltest /sc_query:domain /server:servername | Where {$_ -match '\\\\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'} | 
    Foreach {$matches[1]}
```

Comment: The output is close as I get hostname.domain but would just like the hostname?

Comment: Spot on thanks very much! Would you be able to explain how that regex code works as trying to get my head around regex and finding it a bit confusing.

Comment: The \\\\ is how you specify two backslashes. Since backslash is a metacharacter to use it literally requires escaping it with another backslash.  The parens are a capture group the matched contents of which are put in $matches[1]. `[]+` says to capture one or more characters and the characters can be specified individually or in a range using `-` e.g a-zA-Z specifies all lower & upper case alpha characters. 0-9 specifies all digits and then `_` and `-` as additional valid characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$output = nltest /sc_query:domain /server:servername

$Hostname = ([regex]::Match($output,'(?<=\\\\).+?(?=\.)')).value
```

Edit: Updated Regex to get just hostname.

```
(?<=\\\\) = Positive look-behind for the string `\\` (It will start grab characters after the `\\`)  
.+?        = Any character one or more times
(?=\.)    = Positive look-ahead (It will only grab characters before a `.`)
```

Edit 2: Realized I should make the `+` non-greedy so it would stop at the first `.`.  Adjusted regex for future visitors.

Comment: When I run that I get:  servername.domain Trusted DC Connection Status Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success The command complet
ed successfully. How can I just get the hostname?

Comment: Sorry, I though you're regex was functional from the question.  I updated with a working regex.  It should grab all characters between `\\` and the first `.`  If you have any `.` in the name of the servers that you want to get, you will need to create a more complex regex, and at that point would probably just grab it all and split it later in the code.

Comment: No worries, unfortunately when I run that code in powershell it's still returning the full line containing the hostname and domain name. I.e servername.domain

Comment: What version of powershell are you running?  If you not sure how to check, use `$PSVersionTable` to find out.